# Google pay using Stripe shows error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I integrate google pay using stripe in flutter. Here is my code

[image]

I also create google_pay_payment_profile.json file. Here is my json file
[image]

When i try to payment its show below error

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because Google hasn't allowed your app to use Google Pay in prod. You can refer to this [checklist](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay#going-live) for Going live with Google Pay.

Comment: Thanks to answer but you can find in second screenshot i set environment to Production

Comment: That's actually the problem Ravi. To operate in production, you need to create an account on Google's Pay & Wallet console and submit your integration for approval. In the meantime, you can test your integration using the `TEST` environment.